# hosting node application in the cloud

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple rest api which is returning some static data. I am declaring some simple URL pattern and making requests to my localhost and it returns stuff...works like a charm. This is what I am doing

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
    res.send([{name:'Adam'}, {name:'John'}, {name:'paul'}]);
});
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send({id:req.params.id, name: "The Name", description: "description"});
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

but now I am trying to run it outside my local machine, maybe in the clud. Maybe a test server. I am seeing options where I have to pay to use. Is there some place I can host it for free? This is purely for learning and not for any production purposes

Comment: https://www.heroku.com

Answer (score 1):

You could install a virtual machine on your own computer, using VirtualBox (say Debian). And set up a URL for it in the hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux, windows\system32\drivers\etc on windows) rather than using DNS, so you don't even need to register a domain name. That way it costs nothing, and is safe from any security mistakes you might make. And you get to learn about setting up a server for a node.js environment too.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna go on cloud you can use heroku. Also you have Amazon ec2 option as well.